# How to use time.delta properly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some problems with my code. I'm trying to do substraction between dates but i get errors. I want to get the difference between two dates either with integer of days or months. However, even if i learn the diference between days i get this output:99 days, 0:00:00 and I don't want to get the time statement. Other than that, when I make comparisons to obtain remaining month, I get this: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'datetime.timedelta' and 'int'. How can I convert my r_days as remaining days to integer and also how can I get results for remaining months?

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

exam_date = input('Exam Date: ')
exam_date = datetime.strptime(exam_date,date_format)


if exam_date < (datetime.strptime("05/07/2020", date_format)):
    print('Exam finished')
 
elif exam_date > (datetime.strptime("05/07/2020", date_format)):
    r_day = exam_date - (datetime.strptime("05/07/2020", date_format))
    
    if r_day<30:
    
        print(r_day,"days until the exam")
    else:
        r_months = r_day//30
        print(r_months, "months untill the exam")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the raw timedelta object, use its `days` attribute. And you should save your comparison date rather than using `strptime` over and over:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"

exam_date = input('Exam Date (DD/MM/YYYY): ')
exam_date = datetime.strptime(exam_date,date_format)

compare_date = datetime(2020, 7, 5)
if exam_date < compare_date:
    print('Exam finished')
 
elif exam_date > compare_date:
    r_day_diff = exam_date - compare_date
    
    if r_day_diff.days < 30:
        print(r_day_diff.days,"days until the exam")
    else:
        r_months = r_day_diff.days // 30
        print(r_months, "months until the exam")

else:
  print("Exam is today!")
```